# Content Provider commons

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Few interesting questions about Content Provider mechanism

- Should we use Content Provider, when data are not meant to be shared accross applications?

> Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications. They're the only way to share data across applications; there's no common storage area that all Android packages can access.
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

- When having multiple data tables connected together, should we create single Provider for every data type, or can we use single provider for all of them?
- When mirroring data from remote server, is there any common update mechanism related to Content Provider, or do we have to implement some kind of SyncAdapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we use Content Provider, when data are not meant to be shared across applications?

Content Provider is one of the good features to share data among applications or activities within applications.
If you want to use content provider for your application and don't want to share then you can use content provider and it is really nice abstraction if you use content provider.

> When having multiple data tables connected together, should we create single Provider for 
>   every data type, or can we use single provider for all of them?

For different tables I think you have to create different content provider.In Android there are different content provider for different tables and database.So better you create 
separate content provider for all the tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we use Content Provider, when data are not meant to be shared across applications?

Content Provider is one of the good features provided by Android.
Using it to share data among applications or activities within applications helps in making the code cleaner and quite abstract.

> When having multiple data tables connected together, should we create single Provider for every data type, or can we use single provider for all of them?

All content providers implement a common interface for querying the provider and returning results — as well as for adding, altering, and deleting data. Single provider can be used while working with multiple data tables . Using different content providers will unnecessarily create overhead.

Comment: About your first answer, please, read what am I asking for. I don't want to share data between applications. Is it really useful for accessing data across activities?

Comment: sharing data between activities totally depend upon the requirement.